# About MySQL's Leftmost Prefix Matching Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I now have a table like this：

```
> DESC userInfo;
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | char(32)            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| age    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**I made (name, age) a joint unique index:**

```
> SHOW INDEX FROM userInfo;
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment      |
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| userInfo |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |                    |
| userInfo |          0 | joint_unique_index |            1 | name        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 联合唯一索引       |
| userInfo |          0 | joint_unique_index |            2 | age         | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 联合唯一索引       |
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, when I use the following query statement, its type is All:

```
> DESC SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userInfo | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I can understand this behavior, because according to the leftmost prefix matching feature, age will not be used as an index column when querying.

But when I use the following statement to query, its type is Index:

```
> DESC SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userInfo | NULL       | index | NULL          | joint_unique_index | 132     | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I can't understand how this result is produced. According to Example 1, the age as the query condition does not satisfy the leftmost prefix matching feature, but from the results, its type is actually Index! Is this an optimization in MySQL?

When I try to make sure I use indexed columns as query conditions, their type is always ref, as shown below:

```
> DESC SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE name = "Jack";
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userInfo | NULL       | ref  | joint_unique_index | joint_unique_index | 128     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

> DESC SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE name = "Jack";
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userInfo | NULL       | ref  | joint_unique_index | joint_unique_index | 128     | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Please tell me why when I use age as a query, the first result is ALL, but the second result is INDEX. Is this the result of MySQL optimization?
In other words, when SELECT * is used, index column queries are not applied, but when SELECT joint_col1, joint_col2 FROM joint_col2 are used, index column queries (because type is INDEX) are used. Why does this difference occur?

Comment: *I can't understand how this result is produced.* It is simple. Your index is covering for this query, and the index is used as compact table's copy.

Comment: `age` is a clumsy thing to have in a table -- every row needs to be changed every year.

Comment: For SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18; Will this SQL statement use the joint index of (name, age) to speed up search?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying a bit, an index `(name, age)` is basically the same as if you had another table `(name, age, id)` with a copy of those values. The primary key is (for InnoDB) included for technical reasons - MySQL uses it to find the full row in the original table.

So you can basically think of it as if you have 2 tables: `(id, name, age, gender)` and `(name, age, id)`, both with the same amount of rows. And both have the ability to jump to/skip specific rows if you provide the leftmost columns.

If you do

```
SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18;
```

MySQL has to read, as you expected, every row of the table, as there is no way to find rows with age = 18 faster - just as you concluded, there is no index with age as the leftmost column.

If you do

```
SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18;
```

the situation doesn't change a lot: MySQL will also have to read every row, and still cannot use the index on `(name, age)` to limit the number of rows it has to read.

But MySQL can use a trick: since you only need the columns `name` and `age`, it can read all rows from the index-"table" and still have all information it needs, as the index is a *covering index* (it covers all required columns).

Why would MySQL do that? Because it has to read less absolute data than reading the complete table: the index stores the information you want in less bytes (as it doesn't include `gender`). Reading less data to get all the information you need is better/faster than reading more data to get the same information. So MySQL will do just that.

But to emphasize it: your query still has to read all rows, it is still basically a full table scan ("ALL") - just on a "table" (the index) with less columns, to save some bytes. While you won't notice a difference with one tinyint column, if your table has a lot of or large columns, it's actually a relevant speedup.

Comment: The magic words to type into Google are "covering index"

Comment: For SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18; Will this SQL statement use the joint index of (name, age) to speed up search?

Comment: @YunYaJun I hoped it was clear from my answer - MySQL uses the index, but not to skip rows (which is what you probably think an index is used for, e.g. somehow jumping to the correct age entries), but to read less column (and thus less data). It still reads all rows. I elaborated a bit more, I hope it's clear now (if not, feel free to ask again).

Comment: @symcbean Thanks for the hint, I added the term to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "leftmost" rule applies to the `WHERE` clause versus the `INDEX`.

`INDEX(name, age)` is useful for `WHERE name = '...'` or `WHERE name = '...' AND ((anything else))` because `name` is leftmost in the index.

What you have is `WHERE age = ...` ((and nothing else)), so you need `INDEX(age)` (or `INDEX(age, ...)`).

In particular, `SELECT name, age FROM userInfo WHERE age = 18;`:

```
INDEX(age) -- good
INDEX(age, name) -- better because it is "covering".
```

The order of columns in the `WHERE` does not matter; the order in the `INDEX` *does* matter.